# A few questions about test and performance when have huge number of files on ext4 filesystem

Tags: c++, linux, filesystems, inode, ext4

**filesystem**: ext4 (rw,natime,nodiratime,delalloc,ordered)

**Situation**：
     I have a data server, may have 10 or more disks on it, each disk saves  more than 4 Million files on it. In the previous version of the data server, these files are
under the same directory. for the concern about performance, I add a new feature
to put these files into **1000** hashed directories in the next release.

to present my question simply, let’s say the original directory called ‘**WorkingDir**’,
the new hash directories under WorkingDir called ‘**HashedDir**'

My Question are follows:

- Since lots of deletions and creations of files under the WorkingDir, the WorkingDir maybe very large (since ext4 don’t recycle those deleted node). For this concern, even files are under HashedDir, Is there any performance penalty when RECURSIVE LIST WorkingDir or ACCESS files in HashedDir or some other operations?
- How can I benchmark the performance change between this 2 versions since server don't have a specific access pattern? How do I test? Should I concern about the open Qps or open time distribution or some other things?
- Is there any ways to Recycle those deleted files’ inode under a large directory?

Here are some my thought:

- recursive list WorkingDir may have no change between 2 releases. But file Access latency will decrease when use HashedDir even the WorkingDir is pretty large with lots of deleted inodes
- I should concern about the open file time distribution since the most thing to influence performance is the dentry cache missing times.

Am I right? Anything else I need concern about?

Sorry for my pool english. Thank you all.